# I repaired/was reparing my bike from 2 to 4pm

Tags: past-tense, past-simple, past-continuous

What's the difference between the past simple and the past continuous when using "from ... to ..."?

> I **read** a book *from 2 to 4pm*.
> I **was reading** a *book from 2 to 4pm*.

> I **built** a ship *from 2 to 4pm*.
> I **was building** a ship *from 2 to 4pm*.

> I **repaired** my bike *from 2 to 4pm*.
> I **was repairing** my bike *from 2 to 4pm*.

Comment: Your third example doesn't really work: it implies that a person can build a ship in two hours. (But it might be possible if it was a _model_ of a ship.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is in whether you are choosing to present the activity as a completed whole, or as a process that continued. That is all.

There is no objective difference. There are no implications that are different.

There *might* be (but would not necessarily be) some different implications in what follows that statement. So if the next sentence after any of them was *John came to talk to me*, then with the "continuous" forms there is a suggestion that this happened during the activity, whereas with the simple past forms there is no such suggestion: it might have been during or after the activity. And even with the continuous forms, that suggestion could be overridden by something else in the discourse.

Comment: Thank you! 
> _The diffference is in whether you are choosing to present the activity as a completed whole, or as a process that continued. That is all._
Do I get it right: if I didn't finish/build the ship in two hours, I can't say "I built it from 2 to 4pm", only "I was building it from 2 to 4pm", right?

Comment: @IlyaTretyakov Sometimes you can talk about incomplete actions using the past simple: It is perfectly fine to say, for example "I read my book from 2 to 4" even if you didn't finish it.  In the case of 'build', the verb itself implies that the action is finished.

Comment: Yes. I would think the primary difference is that you only use "I was playing" when you want to say something about the time at which it happened: "The plane crashed at 10:30a.m. I was playing tennis at the time". With "I played tennis" the focus is on the activity, not the time at which it occurred: "I once played tennis against Mary. She beat me easily."

Comment: @MichaelKay sorry, that's not what I'm asking about. I'm trying to find out whether I can use **the past simple** with "from .. to.." even if I didn't finish the book/the ship etc. or is it necessary to use **the past continuous.** Examples: I read a book from 2 to 4pm. I wrote a book from 2 to 4pm. I built a ship from 2 to 4pm. (None was complete)

Comment: @IlyaTretyakov: When the action is clearly [telic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telicity), (eg _I baked a cake_) then the past simple implies it was complete. But _read a book_ is not clearly telic - it can be used either way. _Built a ship_ is probably telic, but I don't think it has to be.

Comment: @ColinFine thanks! So, as I understand it now; the verbs used in the simple aspect imply completion unless they're used with **"from .. to ..", "for", "until" and "while".** These four (so-called "time markers") show incompletion of the object but ONLY if the verb can be used in imperfect sense. Is this correct? And is there any source of information which verbs have only perfect meaning and which can have both (with those four time markers)?

Comment: @ColinFine I've been taught that if I don't know whether the object was complete (the case when in Russian I use imperfect form of a verb), I should use "spend time building/painting etc.", but there is a big problem. **I'll try to show it in this context:** A: What did your wife do yesterday evening after coming back from work? B: Nothing special, she cooked dinner. A: And **what did you do while she cooked?** B: I spent some time reparing. A: **What did you repair?** B: **My truck.** (the last two sentences clearly show "I repaired my truck", but it isn't ready yet,because it takes many days

Comment: The "was xxx-ing" forms feel much more natural to me, but I've no idea why that should be the case. Probably, I think, because "I was XXX from 2pm to 4pm" tends to describe a state I was in throughout that period of time, so "I was cycling" or "I was reading" fit that pattern; they leave it open whether the activity continued after the specified period of time. But some sentences in the other format seem to work as well: "I worked in the garden from 2pm to 4pm", with a clear implication "and then I stopped".

Answer (score 5):

In terms of literal meaning, they are equivalent. The difference is one of *emphasis*.

### Main Events

The first reason to use the past continuous is to emphasize the *main event* of some story. If several things were happening, placing the main one in the past simple and the rest in past perfect serves to emphasize the main event. For example:

> I *was walking* down the street--*listening to* music--and suddenly this guy **jumped** out at me!

### Experience of Continuous Action

The other main reason one might use past continuous is to draw attention to the experience of an ongoing event. The past can be used to emphasize *the experience* of an *ongoing* event. This is a more subtle difference.

To give a practical example:

> 1. I *was working* in the field yesterday.
> 2. I worked in the field yesterday.

To my ear, (1) brings to mind the action and experience of field work: standing in the field, under the sun, etc. The speaker experienced the action "working in the field." (2) lacks such associations; to me (2) is more clear and businesslike: yesterday the speaker did work in the field.

Another example:

> 1. I was trying as hard as I could to lift it.
> 2. I tried as hard as I could to lift it.

As above, (1) brings to mind someone straining against the load, red in the face, etc. They are in the middle of trying. (2) is more matter-of-fact. The speaker tried as hard as he/she could, but now it is over.

Comment: I think even your first example is the most clear of all of them here - When you say `this guy jumped out at me` I think of it as something that happened once, like someone tried to scare you. If you said it, `this guy was jumping out at me` makes it sound like a continuous action (harassment) like he wanted to fight.

Answer (score 2):

To add to the previous answers, as a native speaker, in the examples given the past continuous is far more natural than using the past simple. This is particularly because the subject is an activity which took place over a period of time. I think the other answers are much more applicable when the "... from ... to ..." are not part of the sentence. In short:

> I repaired my bike *yesterday*.

sounds just as natural as:

> I was repairing my bike *yesterday*.

but

> I repaired my bike from 2 to 4 pm.

does not sound right (although it technically is); it would be more natural to say

> I was repairing my bike from 2 to 4 pm.